# Easiest way to connect to a junction box when the wires won't reach?

Tags: wiring, junction-box

I got a new attic fan, and the wires won't quite reach to the junction box that the old fan was wired to. What's the easiest way to complete this connection in a code-compliant manner? Everything is easily accessible as it's all mounted to the roof rafters.

Should I unmount the current junction box and see if there's enough slack in the wires to move it over a couple of inches? Mount a new junction box to connect to both the fan and the old junction box? Something else entirely?

Comment: Nothing in EMT is easy; which is where "wires" go. Y'all are talking about *cable*, where everything is easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can already see that there is enough slack in the wires feeding the junction box, then go ahead and move it. DO NOT just pull the wires to test for excess slack. You run the risk of dragging the wires over something sharp, or pulling the other end out of whatever it's connected to.

Depending on the design of the fan, it might be easy to remove the existing cord and connect a new, longer one.

Otherwise just install a new junction box where convenient, and connect it to the old junction box, as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Any thoughts on the relative simplicity/cost of using one of those cable splice kits instead of installing a new junction box?

Comment: Depending on the type of splice kit, it may have to be enclosed anyway. Many of those kits are intended to end up behind drywall, etc., so be careful which you choose.